# How to detect if current project is an app, a shared library or dynamic library in qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a .pri file which can be included both in a library project and in an app project. Some details in there are dependent on the current build type (lib or app).

What is the recommended way to detect if the current project is either an executable, a static library or a dynamic library?

Comment: Did you try `TEMPLATE` variable ? Docs here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html#project-templates

Comment: The `TEMPLATE` variable seems to be a possibility to detect `app` or `lib`, but not the static / dynamic case, which results in a mixture of things in the `CONFIG` variable. So I was hoping that there is something more generic here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the recommended way to detect if the current project is either an executable, a static library or a dynamic library?

The bundled scripts do inspect `TEMPLATE` and `CONFIG` variables. Here is an example code to perform such tests:

```
defineReplace(projectType) {
    contains(TEMPLATE, ".*lib") {
        CONFIG(shared, static|shared): return("dynlib")
        return("lib")
    }
    contains(TEMPLATE, ".*app"): return("app")
    return("other")
}

# example usage
prj = $$projectType()
equals(prj, "app"): message("Building the application")
else: message("Doing something different")
```